# Arraylist with an class named Item

Tags: java, arraylist

Create an array that contains Item objects with the serial numbers, names and 
unit prices.

Allow a user to enter the serial number of an Item and print all the details of the 
Item if it is in the array, otherwise state that the Item is not found.

Allow a user to enter the unit price of an Item and print the name of the Item if it 
is in the array, otherwise state that the Item is not found.

**What I did**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UseItem {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Item> aList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    aList.add(new Item(1234, "Saw",          153.75));
    aList.add(new Item(9876, "Hammer",        47.50));
    aList.add(new Item(6432, "Drill",        272.99));
    aList.add(new Item(4682, "I-Beam Level", 240.00));
    aList.add(new Item(2909, "Shovel",        75.00));

    System.out.println("If you would like to print detalis by Serial number press 1 ");
    System.out.println("If you would like to print detalis by Price number press 2 ");

    int a = s.nextInt();

    if (a == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter Serial Number");
        int sn = s.nextInt();

        for (int i =0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            Item i1 = aList.get(i);
            int sern = i1.getSerialNumber();
            if (sn == sern)
                i1.printDetails();
            else 
                System.out.println("Item not found");
        }
    }

    if (a == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Price");
        double p = s.nextDouble();

        for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            Item i1 = aList.get(i);
            double pr = i1.getUnitPrice();
            if (p == pr) {
                i1.printDetails();
            } else 
                System.out.println("Item not found");
        }

    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it does go through the loop and get the answer but it says item not found mutiple times.

Comment: Move `System.out.println("Item not found");`out of the for loop.

Comment: Would it still go through and print whether the item is there or not? If I move it out of the loop

Comment: @shaniasingh Yes it would. I would recommend to create a separate method.

Comment: No, you will need to somehow flag that you found or not an item.

Comment: You need to learn and practice doing mental walk-throughs of your code asking yourself at each line -- "does this make sense?" and "what does this line do?" -- also known as "[Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)".

Comment: Have a look at something like [this](https://gist.github.com/glains/1f1be76c91a368c89a74d008dd6457a3), but try to understand why it works and what is different.

Answer (score 1):

*Some general guidelines to help improve the code, coding style...*

Remember, 90% of the life of a program is spent maintaining it!
You want it to be as readable and understandable as possible. Not just for others, for you too. Because when you start writing a lot of code, code you wrote even a couple of weeks or months or years ago can become easily forgotten and confusing even to you.  So styling your code for easier visual separation and naming things very carefully becomes really helpful for quickly studying and troubleshooting code and just to look neat and consistent, just like a well-written and formatted essay does... considerate to the reader...

Specifically from the original code example posted:

1. It is worth the extra effort to find common/popular styles of styling your Java. In the real world, most projects or project gates disallow non-styled code. People see C and Java and read there are no language-specific rules about clean formatting, but that doesn't mean it's not important to make code clear, consistent, easy to read and maintainable as possible. A lot of new coders cram everything together without spaces between braces, and operators, etc... But that is a bad practice professionally. Look at big projects on the net, github, read their code styling guidelines. Some examples:

   Google: 
    http://google.github.io/styleguide/

   Apache: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Code+Style+Guide

   Apache C: https://httpd.apache.org/dev/styleguide.html

   MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html

   NASA:  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19950022400

   That's just a few I found immediately. Most big projects have those requirements.

2. On the line `int sern = i1.getSerialNumber()`; Notice you only reference `sern` on the very next line, only once and it will never be used again. And `sern` is okay but it's not as clear as `getSerialNumber()`, so in that case it would be clearer and simpler and less 'waste' of variables and less work for the garbage collector to just do `if (i1.getSerialNumber())` ...
3. Another thing is intelligent variable naming is extremely helpful for debugging and some product gates are very strict about variable naming to (some require prefixes that indicate the type of the variable in the name even with abbreviated codes). I mention this because `i1` is not a good name for an item, because in the big world, `i` is typically used for indices, so `i1` seems like a 2nd index or how people might use `i, j` indices. And what does it save you in name length? Not much! `item1` would be a better name for that. No one will see that name and ever be confused about what it is.